# Localization of iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I tried to Localized my app English to French but i've Trouble the problem,i Converted into Strings English to French Language here the Below Screen Shots About English And French.

[image]

French Language

[image]

but i didn't Get response in my app can you please suggest me,any changes....!

Comment: how are you creating the strings in your code?

Comment: the selecting xib's to  Language "use internationalization" then after i will selected the localized Language.And modifies to strings English to French @DaSilva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the way to `Localization`.

Make the Localized Strings follow the Below Steps

1. First we select the language into editor area

[image]

2.then after we choose the different languages.

[image]

3.Next Click the Use Base INternationalization

[image]

Now,Click the Finish button.

4.The next step Localize the our Xib files like this

[image]

5.Then,covert to the Xib files to localizedStrings
finally get the Localized strings like

[image]

6.And add the one file into our project i.e

[image]
Click Next and Save the file name Localized.

7.Now Localized.Strings file add to localize languages

[image]

Final step is Go to Click the  Product->Scheme->New Scheme
And Select the AppleLanguages

[image]

and what we want change language called like this code

[image]

Finally i found the how to Localization.